# Optimize MySQL my.conf

Tags: php, mysql

I works with mampp and so mysql.
I'd like to optimise mysql server with my.conf but I don't really find how.
Indeed the server is a production computer with only mammp running.
Storage engine is InnoDB. In the database, there's about 120 table, in main tables there's about 100000 records.

Can you help me to configure my server.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Configure for what? heavy insert? heavy read? Someone's suggested configuration could torpedo performance because you're NOT using that suggested workload. As such, your question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

Read everything here:
http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/